# Catch action from previous view controller in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, controller, segue, cell

I am beginner in programming and i am trying to populate cell in mu second view controller with two different arrays depend on which section is clicked in previous view controller. I'm not sure how can i catch action from previous controller and what way should be used for populating Cell in second viewController in different cases.

////this works fine..

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 2
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.mainSectionsArray[indexPath.section]

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
//MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

         self.performSegueWithIdentifier("popularSpotIdentifier", sender: self)
```

///but here not..

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.favouriteMuseumArray.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CityCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let selectedSection = indexPath.section
    if  selectedSection == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.favouriteCitySpotsArray[indexPath.row].name

    } else if selectedSection == 1 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.favouriteMuseumArray[indexPath.row].name
    }
    return cell

}
```

i tried to set selected section to indexPath.section but since that happens in previous view controller result is not as it is in code above..

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please, edit your question tags... for example: in which language are you programming?

Comment: edited, thx for notice..

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is the answer if anybody had a same problem.

//i recently changed table view to collection view but their methods are pretty much the same

here im using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier method to initialise next view controller im pushing on.

//main view controller

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MainCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCellCollectionViewCell
    cell.mainLabel.text = self.mainSectionsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.mainImageView?.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

//MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        let favSpot = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FavouriteControllerID") as! FavouriteCollectionViewController
        favSpot.selectedSpot = 0
        navigationController?.pushViewController(favSpot, animated: true)
    } else {
        let museumSpot = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FavouriteControllerID") as! FavouriteCollectionViewController
        museumSpot.selectedSpot = 1
        navigationController?.pushViewController(museumSpot, animated: true)
    }
```

im also setting value of //selectedSpot so i can use that in condition in next view controller

//next view controller

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedRow = indexPath.row
    if selectedSpot == 0 {
        let mapCitySpot = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MapStoryboardID") as! MapViewController
        let citySpot = popularSpotArray[selectedRow]
        mapCitySpot.favouriteSpot = citySpot
        navigationController?.pushViewController(mapCitySpot, animated: true)

    } else {
        let mapMuseumSpot = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MapStoryboardID") as! MapViewController
        let museumSpot = museumSpotArray[selectedRow]
        mapMuseumSpot.favouriteSpot = museumSpot
        navigationController?.pushViewController(mapMuseumSpot, animated: true)
    }
}
```